# Teradata SQL Asst query - Error in where clause

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

I have included one 'where' clause which I was hoping to return output with reference to current_date but I am getting an error. Can someone please take a look at it and let me know what exactly I am doing wrong here. Snap attached here.

```
                      AND CASE WHEN (SELECT
                                        CASE TD_Day_of_Week (CURRENT_DATE)
                                        WHEN 1 THEN 'MON'
                                        WHEN 2 THEN 'TUE'
                                        WHEN 3 THEN 'WED'
                                        WHEN 4 THEN 'THU'
                                        WHEN 5 THEN 'FRI'
                                        WHEN 6 THEN 'SAT'
                                        WHEN 7 THEN 'SUN'
                                        ELSE 'Unknown'
                                        END) <> 'MON' THEN tpd."RELATIVE_GLOBAL_DAY" = -1
                                        ELSE tpd."RELATIVE_GLOBAL_DAY" = -3 
                                        END
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the intention here is to restrict the `TD_Day_of_Week` day of the week to not being Monday.  If so, then just directly add that assertion, sans the bulky `CASE` expression:

```sql
WHERE (TD_Day_of_Week (CURRENT_DATE) <> 1 AND tpd."RELATIVE_GLOBAL_DAY" = -1) OR
      tpd."RELATIVE_GLOBAL_DAY" = -3
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim
Here is what I am trying to do;
When user checks data on Tue, they should see the data until until Mon (Prev day). But when the user does it on Mon, they should get data for Fri (Prev weeks).
The db is defined as such that tpd."RELATIVE_GLOBAL_DAY" is '0' for today. If I wanted to go back one day, its then '-1'.

I need to keep SELECT statement part and its output like 'Mon' because the same I can ref in the db

Comment: I have rewritten your stated logic in a valid way.

Comment: I tried above, its returns blank. That's incorrect output.
I modified a little putting same in the 'case when' clause but looks like I am doing something wrong.
Can you please take a look ----->>

and case when TD_Day_of_Week (CURRENT_DATE) <> 1 then tpd."RELATIVE_GLOBAL_DAY" = -1
        else tpd."RELATIVE_GLOBAL_DAY" = -3 end

Comment: Answer has been updated per your requirements.

Comment: Hey @Tim, Thanks much.
Sorry, it looks like I am not defining the problem correctly here. 
This here ----> (TD_Day_of_Week (CURRENT_DATE) <> 1 AND tpd."RELATIVE_GLOBAL_DAY" = -1) ----> We cannot put in 'AND'. The ---> "RELATIVE_GLOBAL_DAY" = -1 ---> meant that we wanted to call yesterdays data. 

Eg. Today is Tue so condition has to ---> if TD_Day_of_Week (CURRENT_DATE) <> 1 then get data of Mon ---. which we can do by using db in td ods_vw_ac_db.TIME_PERIOD_DATE  as tpd and col name as tpd."RELATIVE_GLOBAL_DAY" = -1

Comment: Since TD_Day_of_Week (CURRENT_DATE) <> 1 and tpd."RELATIVE_GLOBAL_DAY" = -1 cannot be joined directly, in my understanding it needs to done with 'Case when' clause.

I hope this helps you understand. Again, sorry for confusion.

Comment: So maybe you just want to compare with the result of a case expression, like `CASE WHEN TD_Day_of_Week(CURRENT_DATE) = 1 AND tpd.RELATIVE_GLOBAL_DAY = -1 THEN -3 ELSE tpd.RELATIVE_GLOBAL_DAY END`